# foreach duplicate check box fields

Tags: php, mysql

I get values to "**$val**" **1** and **4**. The **products_extra_fields_id 1 and 4** have checkbox field checked plus another checkbox in other **products_extra_fields_id's** I have two checkboxes. How can I avoid duplicate checkbox fields.

```
<?php                       
$extra_fields_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_extra_fields");
while ($extra_fields = mysql_fetch_array($extra_fields_query)){

    foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS['extra_field'] as $key=>$val){
//$val get values 1 and 4

        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='extra_field[".$extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id']."]' value='".$extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id']."' " . (($extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id'] == $val) ? checked : false). " >";
    }
    } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please be more explicit on the expected behaviour and the one you actually have ? Could you join a dump of your 'arrayExtraFieldId' and the function "tep_draw_checkbox_field" 's declaration ?

Comment: give more info about your problem and select only required field not all it will slow your processing.

Comment: I use while for retrieve checkbox fields from mysql and foreach with POST VARS for checked checkbox fields, I edit my code look to second foreach

Comment: @SuchitKumar any idea for my edit code

Comment: `if ( ($checked == true) || (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS[$name]) && is_string($HTTP_GET_VARS[$name]) && (($HTTP_GET_VARS[$name] == 'on') || (stripslashes($HTTP_GET_VARS[$name]) == $value))) || (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS[$name]) && is_string($HTTP_POST_VARS[$name]) && (($HTTP_POST_VARS[$name] == 'on') || (stripslashes($HTTP_POST_VARS[$name]) == $value))) ) ` - oh god, my eyes are bleeding. refactoring? https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method

Comment: @SuchitKumar I delete function declaration with tep_draw_checkbox_field(..., I stop your eyes bleeding. -)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, sorry it was mistake, I edit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing duplicate checkboxes because, for every row you pull from the database, you are looping over the `extra_field` data posted by the user. There are two values in `$HTTP_POST_VARS['extra_field']` so you get two checkboxes per row.

Instead of `($extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id'] == $val)` you should use `in_array` to test whether the checkbox is checked in each case.

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is very old and was deprecated in PHP 4.1 in 2001. Instead you should use `$_POST` which is a superglobal. This means you do not have to use `global` before using it in a function.

`checked` is a string and should be enclosed in quotes in your `echo` statement.

The following should fix all these issues:

```
$extra_fields_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_extra_fields");
while ($extra_fields = mysql_fetch_array($extra_fields_query)) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='extra_field["
      . $extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id'] . "]' value='"
      . $extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id'] . "' "
      . (in_array($extra_fields['products_extra_fields_id'], $_POST['extra_field'])
           ? "checked" : "")
      . " >";
}
```